# Bind9 doesn't start on boot with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I'm using a VPS, and with the Ubuntu 16.04 image I can successfully install `bind9`, but it doesn't start on boot. There's no `named` or `bind9` under `/etc/init.d`. Running `service bind9 start` works as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You then may try to manually activate it:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

(legacy) Example:

```
# update-rc.d bind9 enable
```

On systemd, it would be:

```
# systemctl enable bind9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `update-rc.d bind9 enable` gave me the error `update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for bind9`, but `systemctl enable bind9` worked as a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding onto roothahn's answer as I feel it could use a little explanation, what you will want to do is `systemctl enable bind9`. Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd instead of init, so most services are done via `systemctl`, rather than `service` and /etc/init.d scripts (which I assume still exist for compatibility reasons).

In terms of starting, restarting and stopping services, it's not a huge change.  For example, you would do `systemctl restart ssh` instead of `service ssh restart`, `systemctl stop mysql` instead of `service mysql restart`, etc. The program name now comes last, which makes it easier to alias (I have `:r` aliased to `systemctl reload-or-restart`, so I can just `:r ssh` to restart sshd)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll keep that in mind. What puzzles me is that in general doing an `apt-get install` of a service tends to set it up so that it starts on boot. Maybe it's something Ubuntu will polish in future versions?

Comment: Yeah, I find that odd too. That's something strange that I've always known Ubuntu/Debian to do.

Comment: some services are not boot-enabled by default, that's decided by the package maintainers. btw, you can just use "apt" now (since trusty).

Comment: I also wondered why the manpage I linked to is for xenial, since I was sure it uses systemd now, but I had no xenial by hand to validate